# loop through rows and check on screen which checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function checkPeriods(ePeriodId, eType, eStart, eEnd)
{
     var found = false;


     #foreach($e in $existing_periods)
              if(document.getElementById("chk").checked)
             {

             $('#periods tbody tr').each(function()
                {
                    var stDt = $('select[name$="start_y"]', this).val() + $('select[name$="start_m"]', this).val();
                    var enDt = $('select[name$="end_y"]',   this).val() + $('select[name$="end_m"]',   this).val();
                    var Ttype = $('select.type', this).val();

                    if(eType == Ttype && stDt == eStart && eEnd == enDt)
                         found = false;
                });

             }
                else
             {
                 $('#periods tbody tr').each(function()
                 {
                    var stDt = $('select[name$="start_y"]', this).val() + $('select[name$="start_m"]', this).val();
                    var enDt = $('select[name$="end_y"]',   this).val() + $('select[name$="end_m"]',   this).val();
                    var Ttype = $('select.type', this).val();

                    if(eType == Ttype && stDt == eStart && eEnd == enDt)
                         found = true;
                });

             }
    #end

   if(found == false)
    {
        alert('Selected Period is not defined. Please define same and check this existing period');
        document.getElementById("chk").checked = false;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

//Html

```
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chkPeriodID[$e.Periodid]" onclick="checkPeriods('$e.Periodid', '$e.Type1', '$e.Start1', '$e.End1');"/></td><td>$e.Type</td><td>$e.Start</td><td>$e.End</td><td>$e.Requestno</td><td>$e.Proposalno</td><td>$e.Workflowstatus<td>$e.Approved_On</td>
        </tr>
```

i want to loop through the data ($existing_periods) and my screen contain 4 chechbox with same id i.e ("chk").My requiremet is-
1) if 2 checkbox check with same data row, it should show validation msg.

Comment: Nothing here about C#: tag removed

Comment: If you have multiple elements with the same id you then you cannot use those ids because ids are required to be unique. The browser could do anything when looking for elements with duplicate ids.

Comment: when page rendered, 4 rows get generated with same checkbox id. how i loop through that checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a list of all checked checkboxes on the page, you don't need to loop through anything, just use this selector:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

You do need to fix your duplicate-ID problem, however: element IDs must be unique within the DOM.  Best to change that to a className instead:

```
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" ...>
```

(and can then use that classname in the selector as well to select only the checked ones):

```
$('input.chk:checked');
```

As for your specific requirement,

> 1) if 2 checkbox check with same data row, it should show validation msg.

you haven't provided enough context to give an exact answer, but based on the description it would probably look something like this:

```
$('tr').each(function() { // iterate over data rows, assuming they're in a table
  if ($(this).find('input.chk:checked').length === 2) { // two checked boxes in this row
    // show the validation message for this row:
    $(this).find('.classnameForValidationMessage').show();
  } else { /* hide it */ } 
});
```

Comment: As i provided in html, its a table having id "datatble" and  having one tr. at runtime no.of tr get generated like- row 1 - _'checkbox'_ _ 'startDate'_ _'EndDate'_. row 2 - 'checkbox' 'startDate' 'EndDate'  row 3- 'checkbox' 'startDate' 'EndDate' and so on

Comment: i need a validation here which compare 2 checkboxes with same startDate and EndDate should not be allowed.of course, it shows validation on the second click of the checkbox not the 1st.   here i'm having the data of all the rows which generated runtime.

Comment: Why was none of that information included in the question?